# Using FirestoreRecyclerAdapter but phone's screen looks separately

Tags: firebase

I'm using FirestoreRecyclerAdapter and faced with the problem.
My challenge is that I can add documents and retrieve them the recyclerview but for some reason, thw phone's screen looks separately as attached phone's schreenshot.

how can I do?
Thank You.

This is Adapter;

```
public MyFriendsAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ProfileModelClass> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyFriendsViewholder holder, int position, @NonNull ProfileModelClass model)
{
    holder.myNickname.setText(model.getNickname());
    holder.myAge.setText(model.getAge());
    holder.myGender.setText(model.getGender());
    holder.myDistance.setText(model.getDistance());
    holder.myUserDescription.setText(model.getUserDescription());
    holder.myMarriage.setText(model.getMarriage());
    holder.myAddress.setText(model.getAddress());

    //  String visit_user_id = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();

    //  Intent chatIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);
    //  chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", visit_user_id);
    //  startActivity(chatIntent);

    Glide.with(holder.myProfileImageView.getContext()).load(model.getProfileImage()).into(holder.myProfileImageView);
    Glide.with(holder.myPictureOne.getContext()).load(model.getPictureOne()).into(holder.myPictureOne);
    Glide.with(holder.myPictureTwo.getContext()).load(model.getPictureTwo()).into(holder.myPictureTwo);

}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyFriendsViewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_friends_list_layout,
            parent, false);
    return new MyFriendsViewholder(view);
}

class MyFriendsViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    CircleImageView myProfileImageView;
    TextView myNickname,myAge, myGender, myDistance, myUserDescription, myMarriage, myAddress,
            myFriendsProfile, SendMessageButton;
    ImageView myPictureOne, myPictureTwo;

    public MyFriendsViewholder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        myProfileImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_friends_profile_image_layout);
        myNickname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_friends_nickname_layout);
        myGender = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_friends_gender_layout);
        myAge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_friends_age_layout);
        myDistance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_friends_distance_layout);
        myUserDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_friends_description_layout);
        myMarriage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_friends_marriage_layout);
        myAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_friends_address_layout);
        myPictureOne = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_friends_post_image_first);
        myPictureTwo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_friends_post_image_second);

        myFriendsProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_friends_information_layout);
        SendMessageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_friends_call_layout);

        myFriendsProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(itemView.getContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
            }
        });

        SendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(itemView.getContext(), ChatActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
```

This is MainActivity;

```
private DatabaseReference UsersRef;
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference firstUsersProfilesColRef = db.collection("usersProfiles");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFirestoreList = findViewById(R.id.all_users_list);
    
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("allUsers");

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("홈");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ToolbarProfileBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_profile_button);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawable_layout);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            UserMenuSelector(item);
            return false;
        }
    });

    ToolbarProfileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            SendUserToSetupActivity();
        }
    });

    DisplayAllUsersList();
    
}

private void DisplayAllUsersList()
{
    Query salaryQuery = firstUsersProfilesColRef;
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ProfileModelClass> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ProfileModelClass>()
            .setQuery(salaryQuery, ProfileModelClass.class)
            .build();
    adapter = new MyFriendsAdapter(options);

    mFirestoreList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mFirestoreList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mFirestoreList.setAdapter(adapter);
}



@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    adapter.startListening();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null)
    {
        SendUserToLoginActivity();
    }
    else
    {
        CheckUserExistence();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
   adapter.stopListening();
}
```

This is phone's screenshot;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5TBF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout file `all_friends_list_layout`. I think you have used   `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

**so there you need to use**

```
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Or instead of wrap_content you can also use any value like 150dp or whatever you feel appropriate for your need.

Comment: Thank You very much.

Comment: I use at activity_main.xml "DrawerLayout/FrameLayout/RecyclerView" . RecyclerView does'not work.  What I am using DraweLayout is wrong?

Comment: Joohun , it's quite difficult to say anything without seeing code in this case. Kindly provide some code.